# Dynamically creating EditText with ICS Holo style

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, dynamically-generated

here's my problem: I'm creating an app for ICS using HoloTheme. So by default all EditText views which I implement in .xml-layout look like this: [image]

But when I try to create the same EditText dynamically they all look like EditText in Android 2.3 or etc. (simply white rectangle with borders). Give me please a solution.

Comment: Stackoverflow is nota code generation site.

Comment: I strongly believe that the solution (if it exists) consists of one line of code. I can post here 200 lines of activity code and 50 lines of xml-layout (like almost everyone does) but I hope it's not necessary for this question

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you create them dynamically correct?

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);

EditText et = new EditText(this);


//this would create a 100x50 editText
l.addView(et, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 50));

//and this one would create an editText with relative width and fix height
l.addView(et, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

If, as you said down here, the style of the EditText aren't the ICS ones the problem can be:

- You are not actually programming in the ICS api (in the project you can set that easily in the properties->Android)
- Check in the androidManifest that the minimum-sdk is 13 (4.0.3):

  ```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13">
  ```
- Be sure to have the proper emulator installed (with the api you want).

I hope you can solve your problem with that checks.

Comment: Well, I suppose you haven't understood my question. EditText views are creating correct, but has wrong style

Comment: I tried the code I put right here and it goes fine for me (with the style you want). I'm going to edit my answer with the possible problems you may have.

Comment: I've tried once again: If I create EditText dynamically in onCreate - it works good, but if I do it for example onButtonClick - style fails

Comment: Ok, so finally I've got it: the problem was with my context - using getBaseContext() was bad idea.